# I have PHP form that is pulling information into a dropdown box from SQL Server. I want a particular item in the box as default selected

Tags: php, sql-server

This code is pulling from DB table, and need it to display Information & Tecnology SVCS - 41515 as the default:

```
    echo '<option value=" ' . $row['department']. '"' . ($row['department'] == "INFORMATION & TECHNOLOGY SVCS -41515") ? ' selected="selected"' : "".'>'.$row['department']. '</option>';
```

This Code will give me the drop down but not a selected define item:
echo ''.$row['department']. '';

Department:

```
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT department FROM Department";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
            $query_display = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_display,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        //echo '<option value=" '. $row['department'].' ">'.$row['department']. '</option>';
        echo '<option value=" ' . $row['department']. '"' . ($row['department'] == "INFORMATION & TECHNOLOGY SVCS -41515") ? ' selected="selected"' : "".'>'.$row['department']. '</option>';
        continue;
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: There's no need for `continue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
($row['department'] == "INFORMATION & TECHNOLOGY SVCS -41515")
```

There was a spacing issue. Needed to be

```
($row['department'] == "INFORMATION & TECHNOLOGY SVCS - 41515")
```

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around the conditional expression, because operator precedence is not what you're expecting.

```
    echo '<option value=" ' . $row['department']. '"' . (($row['department'] == "INFORMATION & TECHNOLOGY SVCS -41515") ? ' selected="selected"' : "").'>'.$row['department']. '</option>';
```

To make it easier to read, I usually use a separate variable:

```
if ($row['department'] == "INFORMATION & TECHNOLOGY SVCS -41515") {
    $selected = ' selected="selected"';
} else {
    $selected = "";
}
echo '<option value=" ' . $row['department']. '"' . $selected .'>'.$row['department']. '</option>';
```

Comment: Thanks I have added the parentheses so they the drop down is populating from the table in SQL now I just have to figure out how to get Information & Technology SVCS to be the one that selected from the beginning with form opens.

Comment: That's what this code should do. Make sure the string you're comparing to exactly matches what's in the database -- maybe there's a space between `-` and `41515`?

Comment: @Heidi - If the above doesn't set that row as default, then you should check for spelling errors (casing matters as well). To make sure, copy/paste the output from the database.

Comment: @Heidi It might be better to compare to something simpler, like `$row['department_id'] == 41515`

Comment: you were correct it was a space issue to keep it from populating.  Thanks Barmar